# WiFi strength with Kali linux

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, wifi-configuration

WiFi card is the Realtek RTL8723BE. When i'm on my Windows Partition i get a normal signal and it works OK, but when I switch to Kali, im kinda forced to use my TP-Link TL-WN722N adapter since I get a better signal. I looked into and found the rltwifi_new, I have it installed and such, but that didn't help. I have my /etc/modprob.d/rtl8723be.conf to be "options rtl8723be ips=0 ant_sel=1 fwlps=0".

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MyWiFi"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: MAC
      Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:5   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands to get your laptop's WiFi strength improved.

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
```

Enter the above code in the terminal, and hit enter.
Now enter this command.

```
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

This is temporary. You need to enter these commands again after reboot.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: modprobe command loads proper specified drivers. The second command changes the antenna of the wlan card and thus improves wifi signal. This method is working for me. I'm using HP Notebook af006ax. I'm using kali 2018.2 in it. Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thank you for clarification but please [edit] your answer to add the details you posted in the comment. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy. Comments are considered temporary. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/217657)